# Using Prev and Next in a table format

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a table, in one column I have a link, in the other I have a hidden input field which contains information gathered from a database in a "while" loop. e.g. below:

```
<table>
<?php
while(........){
  echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='#' class='clickme'>View File</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' class='myinfo' value='Hello world' />
        </td>
    </tr>
  ";
}
?>
</table>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickme').on('click', function () {
        var i;
        i = $(this).next('.myinfo').val();

        alert(i);
    });
});
```

Now the above did not work so I tried:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function () {
  var i;
  i = $(this).next('td .myinfo').val();

  alert(i);
});
```

I would like to know how to get that information from the hidden field located in the other table column.

Updated:
[image: Php Loop]

The underline blue is the link to click while the red is the button that is in the other cell that I would like to appear when the link is clicked.

Here is the actual java code:
[image: Javascript]

Above you will see the code that when the link is clicked and the window is in focus then the button should appear.

Below is the actual result that i am looking for:
[image: Actual]
The blue is the link, the red is where the button should appear after the window opens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go back first then to your next `td`

```
i=$(this).closest("td").next('td .myinfo').val();
```

Comment: This is not working. Please note that the information is in a loop, does this makes difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).parent().next('td .myinfo').val();
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code snippet to make it easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: @TimWolla i have updated my questions with visual aid

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ID to "View File" link

```
<table>
<?php
$i = 0;
while(........){
<tr><td>
<a href='#' class='clickme' id="<? echo $i ?>">View File</a>
</td><td>
<input type='hidden' id="myinfo_<? echo $i ?>" class='myinfo' value='Hello world' />
</td></tr>
$i++ // <-- 
}
</table>  


$('.clickme').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
alert($('#myinfo_'+id).val());

});
```